# Stuck on double integral in polar form

Tags: integration

> i) Calculate the following integral using polar coordinates by integrating first with respect to $r$ and the second with respect to $\theta$:
> $$
> I = \int \int_D (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}\, dx dy
> $$
> where $D$ is the interior of a closed curve $x^2+y^2 = 2y$
>
> ii) Write down the integral in (i) as repeated integrals in polar coordinates by integrating first with respect to $\theta$ and second with respect to $r$ (You do not need to calculate the resulting repeated integrals)
>
> iii) Using the result of (i), or otherwise, integralte
> $$
> J = \int \int_D \left( (x^2 + y^2)^{3/2} + y^2 \sin x \right)\, dx dy
> $$

I am having trouble with the above integration. I have done part (i) and part (ii), but I am stuck on part (iii), with integrating $$\iint y^2sin(x)dydx$$

I have changed it into polar form, together with using the integration limits from my solution to part (i)

$$\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2sin(\theta)}(r^3sin^2(\theta)sin(rcos(\theta))  drd\theta$$

I am now trying to integrate the above. I have no clue how to do this integration. I have tried

$$u=rcos(\theta)$$
$$du=cos(\theta)dr$$
and make no progress.. I also don't really know how to do integration by parts for this problem

Any advice or help for the above integration would be great

Comment: You want to integrate $r^2\sin^2(\theta)\sin(r\cos(\theta))$ with respect to $r$ ? Integrate by part.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but I am unsure how to do this integration by parts. Any advice?

Comment: Differentiate $r^2$ and integrate $\sin(r\cos(\theta))$. And do it twice.

Comment: It does not depend on $r$... So you can put it outside from the integral.

Comment: Bare with me I'm new to this site lol. Okay great, so my integral becomes $$\int_0^{\pi}sin^2(\theta)d\theta \int_0^{2sin(\theta}r^3sin(rcos(\theta))dr$$

Comment: But I have a power of $r^3$ because $dA=rdrd\theta$

Comment: Ok, then differentiate the $r^3$ and integrate the other factor.

Comment: I'm real rusty on integration by parts.. I get $u=r^3$ so $du=3r^2dr$ and $v=\int sin(rcos(\theta))$ and so $v=-\frac{cos(rcos(\theta))}{cos(\theta)}$ is this correct?

Comment: I've been working on this problem for hours and make no progress.. Do i need to do integration by parts 3 times in order to make the $r$ term dissapear?

Comment: Yes ! You see that the $r^3$ becomes a $r^2$... Now you can do it again, the $r^2$ will become a $r$, and another time to make the $r$ disappear

Comment: Okay thank you! I have a couple more questions and then I may be equipped to handle this problem haha. Because the integral has the limits $\int_0^{2sin\theta}$ do i have to evaluate these in the uv part of $uv-\int vdu$ each time I do integration by parts?

Comment: Yes, you have to :)